# I want to read and replace string from text file using html textboxes with the help of any javascript or servlet?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<doctype!>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>prashant</title> 
        <style>
            body{
                background: #ffffcc
            }
            form{
                weidth:200px;
                padding:20px;
                margin:auto;
                font-size: 20px;
                align-items: stretch;
                position: inherit;
                border: 1px white solid;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }
            input[type=text]{
                weidth:100;
                padding:5px;
                font-size:17px;
                margin:  20px;
                position:relative;
            }
            input[type=submit]{
                padding: 5px;
                font-size:18px;
                position: relative;
            }
            h3{
               text-align: center;
               font-size: 40px;
            }
          </style> 
       </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <font size="20">
    </font>
    <h3><mark><strong>barcode printing</strong></mark></h3>
            <center>
                <form name="form1" action="./NewServlet" method="modifyFile">
                  
        WARE HOUSE<input type ="text" id="fname"><br>
        ITEM NAME <input type ="text" id="iname"><br>
        SERIAL NO. <input type ="text" name="serial"><br>
    <input type="hidden" form="file" value="38x25prn.txt">
   GROUP<input type ="text" name="group"><br>
        ASP<input type ="text" name="asp"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="print" onclick="loadFileAsText()">  <input type ="submit" value ="close" onclick="close()">
      </form>
</center>
  
 
     </body>
    </html>
```

here is the code please do this as read the file and replace string from text file.
I want to do replace string from text file and by using servlet or by java script.
firstly , I have a html page consist of text box and button and if I write something in that text box and press button then it should have to read a text file in my computer and replace a particular string from that string which I write in that text box .

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: i just only want to read and replace string from text file present in my computer through html text box and after type any thing in html text box if i press button present in html text box it will read and replace the particular string present in text file. that's it

Comment: By `<doctype!>` I think you mean `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use servlet though, at least that's how i think. You can do it like this.

At the jsp page:

```html
<form action="blah" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="textr"> 
<input type="text" name="textn"> 
<input type="submit" value="whatever you want here">
</form>
```

In the servlet doPost() method:

```html
String str=request.getParameter("textr");
String stn=request.getParameter("textn");
String filePath = "Path here";
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
      
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
         buffer.append(sc.nextLine()+System.lineSeparator());
      }
      fileContents = fileContents.replaceAll(textr, stn);
```

Comment: thankx it is working and now i want to print that text file through my printer how to do that .

Comment: i want to print that text file through html print button

Comment: please anybody help me in this

Comment: by print, you mean you want to show its content on the screen?

Comment: no that is a prn file and i want to print that file to print the barcode .label

Comment: i want to send that file to the printer